# how to add items in combox dynamically in tablelayoutpanel in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, combobox, tablelayoutpanel

i have comboboxes dynamically created in a tablelayoutpanel and i want to add items to that combobox dynamically( i dont want to use data sources).

here is my code

```
 Dim cmb(maxx)

    For a = 0 To maxx - 1
        TableLayoutPanel1.Height += 31
        TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 30))
        TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount += 1
        TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(New CheckBox With {.Text = CopyaillongoDataSet.inventory.Rows(a).Item(1).ToString, .Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10)}, 0, TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount - 1)
        TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(New ComboBox With {.Name = cmb(a), .MaxDropDownItems = 10, .DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList}, 1, TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount - 1)
        cmb(a).items.add(a)
    Next
```

i assigned a name to a combobox and tried to use that name to add items but were unsucessful. is it possible to create items dynamically with a combobox dynamically created? if so, can you help me? i am working on my thesis and i need to get rid of this problem. thank you for those who can help.

Comment: your code is creating 2 combos for the same TLP cell.  probably not what you want

Comment: nope its on a different row. but on the same column. i think my code above cannot use a dynamically created name to be used on the next line.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference a control by just a string name the way you are doing it in your code (you didn't post what you are doing between `Dim cmd(maxx)` and the loop, but I'm *guessing* you want to do something like this, where you create a new ComboBox control and add it to the Panel:

```
Dim newCombo As New ComboBox With {.MaxDropDownItems = 10,
                                   .DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList}
newCombo.Items.Add(a)
TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(newCombo, 1, TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount - 1)
```

You can reference the control later with `TableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(column, row)` function.